# How to specify columns SQLAlchemy Insert object and from_select?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm using a SQLAlchemy insert object to quickly insert a bunch of data from another table. The schemas are as follow:

```
create table master (id serial, name varchar);
create table mapping (id serial, new_name varchar, master_id integer);

-- master_id is a foreign key back to the master table, id column
```

I populate my master table with unique names and IDs. I then want my mapping table to get seeded with data from this master table. The SQL would be

```
insert into mapping (master_id, new_name) select id, name from master;
```

I use the following SQLAlchemy statement. The problem I get is that SQLAlchemy can't seem to resolve the names because logically they are different between the two tables.

```
stmt = sa_mapping_table.insert().from_select(['name', 'id'], stmt)
```

Is there a way to tell the insert object, "using this select statement select these columns and put the results in these columns of the target table"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are close but you should specify columns of mapping to insert the select from master into.  This should work where `master_t` and `mapping_t` are the sqlalchemy `Table()` objects.

```py
master_t = Table('master', metadata,
                 Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                 Column('name', String, nullable=False))

mapping_t = Table('mapping', metadata,
                 Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                Column('new_name', String, nullable=False),
                 Column('master_id', Integer, ForeignKey('master.id'), nullable=False))

#...

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    select_q = select(master_t.c.id, master_t.c.name)
    stmt = mapping_t.insert().from_select(["master_id", "new_name"], select_q)
    conn.execute(stmt)
```

Creates the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO mapping (master_id, new_name) SELECT master.id, master.name 
FROM master
```

See the **docs** at
[insert-from-select](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html#insert-from-select)